# Generate a sequence of events based on categorical features

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

What I am trying to achieve is to generate a sequence of events based on some categorical information about a person (gender, age ..)
More exactly I have many persons with a history of diagnoses, and I want to generate a new history of diagnoses on new persons (where each diagnosis is a new event). I also have timestamps information for the diagnoses - but as the time between the events could be varying i think it is better to neglect this information at the start?

Based on the persons age the output sequence should have varying length (as younger people in general have fewer diganoses than older people), and some diagnoses are more likely to be in the beginning of the sequence (children diseases) while some are at the end. Some diagnoses should also just apply to females (miscarriage..)

I have been thinking about this as a sequence generation problem where i might could use recurrent neural networks (?), but i am struggling to get started. I am thinking i should break the problem down to a minimum level in the beginning, as i am not that familiar with neural networks, but i could need a pointer to where i should begin. Or maybe this is not a rnn problem at all?

Right now i have an input vector X which include [year of birth, female, male] where the gender is hot-encoded, and an Y vector with [disease1, disease2 ....] where the diseases are encoded to integers. The Y vectors have varying length. The Y vector could maybe be though of as a time-series, but the input can not (as it is simply just categorical features).

Do anyone have any input of how i should begin? Maybe some tutorials to similar implementations? All inputs are highly appreciated!

I am using Python, and i am most familiar with Keras.
Thank You.

Comment: How high fidelity do you need?

Comment: Not that much, the new data must be realistic, but i do want a bit of randomness as well. there is no absolutely correct answer in medical history.

Answer (score 0):

Ane model would be to estimate the probability of getting a certain diagnosis (per time frame) for each of the categories of interest. Then just draw samples from these distribution to generate diagnosises.

A simple version could take just agegroup, gender as basis for categories. More advanced versions could include past medical history.

Comment: So you are thinking like an iterativ multiclass classification? Would not that be hard when there are 170-200 diagnoses?

Comment: Model does not have to be trained each iteration, just sampled from. And it does not need a classifier either. Just computing the condtional probability for each patient category